# ImportError: cannot import name 'add'

Tags: keras

I am using Tensorflow and Keras.
I wrote codes,

```
from __future__ import print_function

from keras.models import Sequential, Model
from keras.layers.embeddings import Embedding
from keras.layers import Input, Activation, Dense, Permute, Dropout
from keras.layers import add, dot, concatenate
from keras.layers import LSTM
from keras.utils.data_utils import get_file
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences

・
・
・
```

When I run the codes,

```
from keras.layers import add, dot, concatenate
ImportError: cannot import name 'add'
```

error happens.I searched it ,so I know upgrading Tensorflow and Keras maybe effective,so I did it.But same error happens.I am moving the codes in anaconda environment,so is it bad?How should I fix this?

Comment: Layer names start with a capital. You should import `Add`, `Dot`, `Concatenate`.

Comment: @sdcbr I imported it by using capital,but ImportError: cannot import name 'Add' happens...

Comment: Try `Add = keras.layers.Add`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to import a function in Keras, You must begin the name of it by a capital letter.
Therefore, try this :

```
from keras.layers import Add, Dot, Concatenate
```

Comment: thank you for your answer.I wrote your codes,but     from keras.layers import Add, Dot, Concatenate
ImportError: cannot import name 'Add' error happens.Do you know why such an error happens?

Comment: I wrote  `import keras`,so  `match = Dot([input_encoded_m, question_encoded], axes=(2, 2))  NameError: name 'Dot' is not defined` error happens.Is it different error?

Comment: yes,I only run import keras.In this time,the error happens.

Comment: There is a problem in keras installation.